I was pushing commits to my repository and encountered this error :
This is the error message I encountered :

git push -u origin
git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

I already pushed the first commit with the push command but now not able to do so.
vs code log

Tried to check the git remote add origin command still not able to resolve.

Few things you can check for:

Check if the origin is set properly

git remote -v

This command will list out the names with their URLs. If you don't find origin to be set properly, then you can do something like this
git remote add origin <remote_url>


Or if you have already set it once, you don't need to set the upstream again. And it might throw an error if you are setting to the same upstream named "origin". You can simply do this

git push

because you have already set the upstream by providing the -u flag in the first push.
My Opinion:
I like to have control over what repo and what branch, I am pushing my code to all the time. So, what I do is first I set the remote origin like this
git remote add <upstream_name> <remote_url>

Then while pushing the code, I do
git push <upstream_name> <branch_name>

This way I am always sure my code is pushed to the right place. This is just how I like to do. You can try out the suggestions I have mentioned above.
